# For loop operation of a Nested list and list

Tags: python, python-3.x, for-loop

```
G = [100,200,300]
I_cel = [[0.1, 0.2,0.3,0.4],[1,2,3,4],[11, 22,33,44]]
for i in list(range(len(G))):
    V_cel.append([])
    Iph_g = Iph_cal[i]  
    Icel_g = I_cel[i]
    for j in Icel_g:    
        a = math.log((Iph_g - j - I_sat)/I_sat,10) - j*R_se  
        V_cel[i].append(a)
print(V_cel[0])
```

** output is:
`ValueError: math domain error` The arrow point in output is pointed to `a = math.log((Iph_g - j - I_sat)/I_sat,10) - j*R_se`. Looks like it is the source of some math error.  Some help. Everything else is the loop fine when I set `a = i*j`(to check the whole program) and code executed successfully.

Comment: You should use map and list again for list operation.

Comment: I have edited the question. Please, see above. The whole code is working properly. Except some math error involving the `log` function. When I executed the whole program by setting `a = i*j` instead of `log` formula, the program executed successfully. I think some thing amiss in `log` function. Some help please.

Comment: for math.log(a,b), if a=0, it will return you a math domain error. From your code, I cannot seem I_sat and Iph_cal, I guess that is the problem,  this portion "(Iph_g - j - I_sat)/I_sat" euqals o.

Comment: Thanks a ton for putting efforts to understand and analyze the reasons for error. You are true that caculations resulted in log of negative values and math error. I have sorted it out.

Answer (score 0):

```
I_cel = [[0.1, 0.2,0.3,0.4],[1,2,3,4][11, 22,33,44]]
```

I think you missed a comma there.

You are getting a math domain error because `j` is equal to `0` when you evaluate it on `math.log(j,10)`.
Maybe you wanted to do something with the array value rather than its index?

Also, I don't get what are `G` values for. Are them used to set the length of `V_cel`?